# How to disable HeidiSQL trying to sort the Data tab

Tags: heidisql

I have a table with millions of rows in it. Each one of those rows has a lengthy TEXT column.

Whenever I click the Data tab, Heidi runs **this** select instead of a plain one:

```
SELECT  `id`,  LEFT(`huge_text_column`, 256) FROM `huge_table` ORDER BY `huge_text_column` ASC, `id` DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

I've already disabled Preferences -> Data editors -> Remember filters, sorting and [...], launched a new window and saw the same thing happening.

Any way of fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

To disable sorting rows on Data tab you have to manually click on the columns' headers (`huge_text_column` & `id` in your case) a few times until the order triangle icon disappeared on the columns.
This might be tricky for huge tables as re-ordering might be extremely slow.
In this case you need to un-tick 'Remember filters, sorting...' option you mentioned and then restart HeidiSQL.

Comment: Yeah, maybe settings are only saved when quitting (all) active window(s).